Integration using BigFloat in Julia
I have a problem with understanding how calculation with BigFloat works in Julia. I want to calculate an integral using the DoubleExponentialFormulas QuadDE function.
I thought this part would work:
setprecision(BigFloat, 426)
f_int(a,b) = quadde(x->f(x), BigFloat(a), BigFloat(b))[1]

But from what I found it should be like this:
setprecision(BigFloat, 426)
qde = QuadDE(BigFloat; h0=one(BigFloat)/8, maxlevel=10)
f_int(a,b) = qde(x->f(x), BigFloat(a), BigFloat(b))[1]

And all arguments of f should also be BigFloats, for example, f(x) = BigFloat(x)^BigFloat(2) + BigFloat(5)
Why it should be like this?
